# Is there any CPAN module for parsing .DIF (Data Interchange Format) files?

Tags: perl, cpan

Is there any CPAN module for parsing [Data Interchange Format (.DIF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Interchange_Format) files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be.  If you wind up writing one, please consider [contributing it to CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/modules/04pause.html).